# Express: res.send() returns an empty object

Tags: node.js, sql-server, express

I have a setup that uses a MySQL server node and express, I have created an update statement on a SQL file and got it to work with the node via patch request on the postman.
It seems to work and it updates the server, however, when I try to get the recently updated object or even a success message, I get an empty object or nothing, even though the data has been updated.

Can anyone help me get some sort of response on postman?

update.sql

```
UPDATE [dbo].[RetailerThemes] 
SET [Name] = @name,
    [PrimaryColourPalette_main] = @primaryColourPalette_main
WHERE [UniqueThemedPageName] = @UniqueThemedPageName
```

router.js

```
router.patch("/update", internal, async (req, res) => {
try {
    //do the update
    const updateRetailer =
      await retailerController.updateRetailerConfigByName(req, res)
    console.log(`Update Retailer Routes: ${updateRetailer}`)
    
res.status(200).send(
  {updateRetailer}
);
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});
```

controller.js

```
 const updateRetailerConfigByName = async (req, res) => {
    try {
    // Credentials from Request
    let retailername = req.retailername;

    // Data from Repository
    const thisRetailerConfig = await retailerRep.updateRetailerConfigDetails(
      retailername
    );
   
    console.log( `thisRetailerConfig: ${thisRetailerConfig}`)
    
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error)
  }
};
```

repo.js

```
async function updateRetailerConfigDetails(retailername) {
try {
    //RetailerTheme
    const sqlcommanda = await tsql.loadSql(
      "tsql",
      //"GetRetailerThemeByThemedPageName.sql"
      "UpdateRetailer.sql"
    );
    let pool = await sql.connect(sqlConfig);
    const themes = await pool
      .request()
      .input("name", sql.VarChar(150), "b") // change 80700 to variable
      .input("UniqueThemedPageName", sql.VarChar(150), retailername)
      .input("primaryColourPalette_main", sql.VarChar(9), "#c00")
      .query(sqlcommanda)
      
    ;
if (themes.rowsAffected != 1) {
  console.log("Retailer not found for ", retailername, sqlcommanda);
  return { isFound: false };
}
const theme = themes.recordset[0];
console.log(`The Theme: ${theme}`)
return theme;
 } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
    return {};
  }
}
```

Here is a screenshot of what I get on the postman, the update works but the response is an empty object.
[image]

Comment: You have two `res.send` calls, one in `router.js` and one in `controller.js`. This cannot work, you can send only one response.

Comment: @HeikoTheißen Thank you for your reply I have updated the code but I am still getting an empty object

Comment: try adding `return thisRetailerConfig` in the controller

Comment: @traynor That returns an empty object

Comment: well, what does console log before that say, also check `catch` part, it returns an empty object..

Comment: @traynor when I console log thisRetailerConfig I get this on the console: thisRetailerConfig: [object Object]

Comment: you're probably getting an error.. check `let retailername = req.retailername;`, is that maybe undefined.. maybe it should be `req.body.retailername`. try hardcoding theme result, if it returns, then it's sql code

Comment: @traynor already checked that, thats being passed accurately

Comment: no idea.. try with something other than postman.. return statement should stay, because the function wasn't returning anything..